# super(null) : what does this mean?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

```
public TableViewerTest() {
    super(null);
    model = new PlayerTableModel();
}
```

what does super(null) do here. I am new to java so was not able to figure out.

Comment: passing null value(referring it to null) to a super class parameterized constructor

Comment: super(null) is used when the parent class does not have default constructor (with no parameters). Here, the parent class - Person - does not have default constructor. so the sub class used -super(null).                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                               
   class Person {
    Person(String s) {
        super();
    }
}

class Employee extends Person {
    Employee(String s) {
        super(null);
    }

Answer (score 2):

It calls the `constructor` of the super class with parameter `null`.

Answer (score 0):

`super(null)` call a constructor of the super class of `TableViewerTest` which accepts a single reference type argument. It passes `null` to that constructor.